# How do I use ReGex with a webpage

Tags: html, regex, bootstrap-5, phone-number

I just found out about Regex, so sorry if it's a noob question, but I want to use it in a webpage, so I tried it, and it didn't work.  Is there a library? SDK? or line of code I am missing??  Here is the code I have, that isn't working in my bootstrap5 project:

```
 <input name="phone" type ="tel" id="phone" pattern="\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx phone" />
```

Thanks,

Comment: `pattern` is used to validate when you submit a form. Are you looking for something when you enter data?

Comment: You can try [bootstrapvalidator](http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/validators/regexp/)

Answer (score -1):

Pattern is checked against on form submission.

So if you add form tag() and try submit, it will check your pattern

I confirmed your code is working in https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern